# Mocking Context and Providers on JEST

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing

I have a project where I need all the time to test components with auth.

This is a short example on how my auth context is set:

**Navigation/contexts/AuthContext.js**

```
const AuthContext = createContext();

const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(false);
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{auth, setAuth}}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);

export default AuthProvider;
```

I have a screen that I want to test. And this is:

**Navigation/Screens/Components/LoginLoadingScreen.js**

```
import {useAuth} from '../../contexts/AuthContext';

const LoginLoadingScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const {setAuth} = useAuth();
  
  });
```

Ok. Now Im trying to test my LoginLoadingScreen with jest and testing-library

**Navigation/Screens/Components/**tests**/LoginLoadingScreen.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import LoginLoadingScreen from '../../Components/LoginLoadingScreen';
import {render, screen, fireEvent} from '@testing-library/react-native';
import {useAuth} from '../../../contexts/AuthContext';

test('LoginLoadingScreen', () => {
  render(<LoginLoadingScreen />);
});
```

And getting this error:

```
   TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setAuth')

      15 |
      16 | const LoginLoadingScreen = ({navigation}) => {
    > 17 |   const {setAuth} = useAuth();
```

I will have a lot of tests that needs to use mocked auth. So. What is the better way to mock it?

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap the component you are rendering with the provider preferrably using the `wrapper` option, something like this:

```
test('LoginLoadingScreen', () => {
  render(<LoginLoadingScreen />, {
    wrapper: ({children}) => (
      <AuthProvider>
        {children}
      </AuthProvider>
    )
  });
});
```

This will get rid of the error on your console and make the context available to the component.

But this will increase the amount of boilerplate you tests have, in that case I would consider following the setup guide of testing library where it overrides the default render function to use all your application providers

[https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup/)/

Comment: Thanks Lucas. I didnt find on the docs the option to overrides the default render function. Can you get in more details please?